Remote Desktop service not listening for connections
I've been experiencing an unusual issue when connecting to remote machines through RDP and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot it. This problem started when I switched to my new machine, which has different domain policies compared to my previous one. I suspect that the issue may be related to this change. The problem affects my RDP sessions from both Windows 11 and Ubuntu laptops to Windows 11, and it seems that others have encountered similar issues when connecting to server OS.
Periodically, the RDP session abruptly crashes and the user is unable to reconnect unless they start a new local session on the machine or restart the RDP service. I've observed this occurring shortly after starting the RDP session as well as on sessions that have been open for several hours.
I've attempted to search the logs, including the event viewer and other RDP-related logs, but I haven't found any relevant information.
Additionally, I've noticed that when this issue occurs, the RDP port (3389) is not active/listening and is only available for UDP.
Has anyone else encountered this issue? What options do I have for troubleshooting this problem? Any ideas on how to resolve this? Thank you.

If you restart the logonui process on the server, does that fix the login afterhand ? I ask as in Windows Server 2022+ it's a know service that cause such behavior. Often RMM services cause the issue with third part service, so it's to watch what run to debug if it's the case.

As I said, restarting the rdp service is enough to fix it...what I'd really love to know is why the socket that should be listening for connections is dead
